# Property could not be set to a 'String' value, must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I have created my own complex type to populate the results from a stored procedure function import.  The datatype from the SP is an Int and the complex type property is also an Int.  When I run the application, I get an error  **The '' property on '' could not be set to a 'String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'**

```
/// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public Nullable<global::System.Int32> ConfidenceLevel
{
    get
    {
        return _ConfidenceLevel;
    }
    set
    {
        OnConfidenceLevelChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("ConfidenceLevel");
        _ConfidenceLevel = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
        ReportPropertyChanged("ConfidenceLevel");
        OnConfidenceLevelChanged();
    }
}
private Nullable<global::System.Int32> _ConfidenceLevel;
partial void OnConfidenceLevelChanging(Nullable<global::System.Int32> value);
partial void OnConfidenceLevelChanged();
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Stack Trace:   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling[TProperty](Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ..Models.Repository.DataAccess.GetExtractAllLimits() in ...DataAccess.cs:line 19
   at ...GetExtractAllLimits() in ....Service.svc.cs:line 17
   at SyncInvokeGetExtractAllLimits(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)

I have tried setting the property to nullable, and deleted and re-added the property, but still nothing works.

I have noticed some old posts that have pretty much the same question with no answers, is this a bug with EF?

Comment: Well presumably you're trying to set it to a string somewhere... but you haven't shown any of the code involved, so it's very hard to help you. Please provide more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have added some screenshots - I am just simply calling into the function import name, and the result is throwing this error.

Comment: *Where* is the error? Is it an exception? If so, provide a stack trace. If not, please give more details. There's still not nearly enough context here.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have added the stack trace, I also tried setting the property to a string and this worked, which is strange.

Comment: Having the same problem, when the web.api get some load, it starts spitting this. restarting the app pool solves the problem for a while, but the root cause is not clear !